# How to move error text to another location in Elementor forms using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to move the error text in an elementor form to a different location, but I can't.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ5gi.png)

I tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      $(document).on('error', function (e, data) {
        $('div[class="elementor-message elementor-message-danger"]').appendTo('.elementor-field-type-submit');
      });
  }
);
```